# Intrarater reliability test for a single subject?

Tags: repeated-measures, small-sample, reliability, agreement-statistics, precision

I have repeatedly measured the volume of the brain of 1 subject in an MRI study. Measurements were acquired by the same rater (myself) on three separate occasions resulting in three measurements of the subject's brain volume.

Example data

```
                   Measurement 1        Measurement 2     Measurement 3
Brain volume:         1246                  1268               1257
```

Can I assess the intra-rater reliability of the brain volume measurement for a single subject? If so, what statistical test(s) should I perform?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Presuming that you mean "Inter-rater reliability" because you have no replicated measurements within each rater.*

Yes.  But it won't mean very much.  Your measure of reliability is the simple standard deviation (not standard error).

You will have to assume that all variability is due to differences between raters when you (and your audience) will know that it is not.

Here is your problem.  You and two others went and "outlined" the brain on the MRI.  And you got 3 different answers.  But the image was exactly the same so there is a "true" answer and any difference is coming from at least two sources of variability (not from the image).

The first is rater bias.  The second is simple measurement error in the pixelation.  If each of you had done this 5 times, you could form an estimate of measurement error separate from rater bias (this would be intra-rater reliability).  You could then compare inter-rater variability to intra-rater variability.  But you did not.

It would help if you had a "true" value but you do not.

*To Summarize:*

If, as I believe, your goal is to separate rater bias from measurement error.  You do not really have enough information to do this.

Comment: The question description seems to indicate that intrarater reliability is desired, i.e., the same rater provided multiple measures of the same object at different times.